# How to get NodeList param

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I am getting below NodeList in console.log.

```
NodeList[input#p_method_checkmo.radio.validation-passed attribute value = "checkmo", input#p_method_ccsave.radio.validation-passed attribute value = "ccsave"]
```

Can any one please tell how can i get value `ccsave` from this.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to array first

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( nodelist );
```

get the last array item

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( nodelist ).pop();
```

get value property from the last item

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( nodelist ).pop().value;
```